# Split text file into multiple files

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I am having large text file having 1000 abstracts with empty line in between each abstract . I want to split this file into 1000 text files. 
My file looks like

```
16503654    Three-dimensional structure of neuropeptide k bound to dodecylphosphocholine micelles.      Neuropeptide K (NPK), an N-terminally extended form of neurokinin A (NKA), represents the most potent and longest lasting vasodepressor and cardiomodulatory tachykinin reported thus far.  

16504520    Computer-aided analysis of the interactions of glutamine synthetase with its inhibitors.        Mechanism of inhibition of glutamine synthetase (EC 6.3.1.2; GS) by phosphinothricin and its analogues was studied in some detail using molecular modeling methods.
```

Comment: I may suggest to avoid to create too much files or directories in one directory. It can definitely slow down the stat(2) calls. Some thousand is not a big issue, but some ten-thousands can be. Of course this limit is dependent on the machine (HDD), operating system and file system You are using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split a .txt file based on content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544684/split-a-txt-file-based-on-content)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split one file into multiple files based on delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313852/split-one-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-delimiter)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use split and set "NUMBER lines per output file" to 2. Each file would have one text line and one empty line.

```
split -l 2 file
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
awk 'NF{print > $1;close($1);}' file
```

This will create 1000 files with filename being the abstract number. This awk code writes the records to a file whose name is retrieved from the 1st field($1). This is only done only if the number of fields is more than 0(NF)

Comment: Thanks for quick response.It worked but its showing  awk: 9276016 makes too many open files
 input record number 35, file pmid.txt
 source line number 1.  I tried different files for every files its showing error at same line number 35. Does it have any limit

Comment: I faced another problem. My file has some lines starting with Conclusion or Results under Abstract number in such case the command u mentioned generating an extra file with Conclusion and Result name which I Dont want. Please help me out

Answer (score 5):

You could always use the csplit command.  This is a file splitter but based on a regex.

something along the lines of :

```
csplit -ks -f /tmp/files INPUTFILENAMEGOESHERE '/^$/'
```

It is untested and may need a little tweaking though.

[CSPLIT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/c_commands/csplit.html)

Comment: I prefer this over the 'awk' solutions. To split one large file (LDIF format) with empty lines separating the chunks, I used the 'repeat pattern' and 'suppress matching line' options: `csplit -m -f /tmp/files INPUTFILE '/^\s*$/' '{*}'`

Comment: Yeah hooray for csplit. +1.