# Split paragraphs of text file into multiple files based on empty line between each

Tags: unix, awk, split

Previously I asked same sort of question but didn't succeed might be I am not clear in my previous question. Here is the file where I want it to split into 3 files based on empty line between each abstract with abstract number as file name

```
16914261    Energetic basis of molecular recognition in a DNA aptamer.      The thermal stability and ligand binding properties of the L-argininamide-binding DNA aptamer (5'-GATCGAAACGTAGCGCCTTCGATC-3') were studied by spectroscopic and calorimetric methods. Differential calorimetric studies showed that the uncomplexed aptamer melted in a two-state reaction with a melting temperature T(m)=50.2+/-0.2 degrees C and a folding enthalpy DeltaH(0)(fold)=-49.0+/-2.1 kcal mol(-1). These values agree with values of T(m)=49.6 degrees C and DeltaH(0)(fold)=-51.2 kcal mol(-1) predicted for a simple hairpin structure. Melting of the uncomplexed aptamer was dependent upon salt concentration, but independent of strand concentration. The T(m) of aptamer melting was found to increase as L-argininamide concentrations increased. Analysis of circular dichroism titration data using a single-site binding model resulted in the determination of a binding free energy DeltaG(0)(bind)=-5.1 kcal mol(-1). Isothermal titration calorimetry studies revealed an exothermic binding reaction with DeltaH(0)(bind)=-8.7 kcal mol(-1). Combination of enthalpy and free energy produce an unfavorable entropy of -TDeltaS(0)=+3.6 kcal mol(-1). A molar heat capacity change of -116 cal mol(-1) K(-1) was determined from calorimetric measurements at four temperatures over the range of 15-40 degrees C. Molecular dynamics simulations were used to explore the structures of the unligated and ligated aptamer structures. From the calculated changes in solvent accessible surface areas of these structures a molar heat capacity change of -125 cal mol(-1) K(-1) was calculated, a value in excellent agreement with the experimental value. The thermodynamic signature, along with the coupled CD spectral changes, suggest that the binding of L-argininamide to its DNA aptamer is an induced-fit process in which the binding of the ligand is thermodynamically coupled to a conformational ordering of the nucleic acid.    

16917835    Enantioselective separation and online affinity chromatographic characterization of R,R- and S,S-fenoterol.     BACKGROUND: rac-Fenoterol is a beta2-adrenoceptor agonist (beta2-AR) used in the treatment of asthma. It has two chiral centers and is marketed as a racemic mixture of R,R'- and S,S'-fenoterol (R-F and S-F). Here we report the separation of the R-F and S-F enantiomers and the evaluation of their binding to and activation of the beta2-AR. 
METHODS: R-F and S-F were separated from the enantiomeric mixture by chiral chromatography and absolute configuration determined by circular dichroism. Beta2-AR binding was evaluated using frontal affinity chromatography with a stationary phase containing immobilized membranes from HEK-293 cells that express human beta2-AR and standard membrane binding studies using the same membranes. The effect of R-F and S-F on cardiomyocyte contractility was also investigated using freshly isolated adult rat cardiomyocytes.
RESULTS: Chiral chromatography of rac-fenoterol yielded separated peaks with an enantioselectivity factor of 1.21. The less retained peak was assigned the absolute configuration of S-F and the more retained peak R-F. Frontal chromatography using membrane-bound beta2-AR as the stationary phase and rac-3H-fenoterol as a marker ligand showed that addition of increasing concentrations of R-F to the mobile phase produced concentration-dependent decreases in rac-3H-fenoterol retention, while similar addition of S-F produced no change in rac-3H-fenoterol retention. The calculated dissociation constant of R-F was 472 nM and the number of available binding sites 176 pmol/column, which was consistent with the results from the membrane binding study 460 +/- 55 nM (R-F) and 109,000 +/- 10,400 nM (S-F). In the cardiomyocytes, R-F increased maximum contractile response from (265 +/- 11.6)% to (306 +/- 11.8)% of resting cell length (P < 0.05) and reduced EC50 from -7.0 +/- 0.270 to -7.1 +/- 0.2 log[M] (P < 0.05), while S-F had no significant effect.
DISCUSSION: Previous studies have shown that rac-fenoterol acts as an apparent beta2-AR/G(s) selective agonist and fully restores diminished beta2-AR contractile response in cardiomyocytes from failing hearts of spontaneously hypertensive rats (SHR). Here we report the separation of the enantiomers of rac-fenoterol and that R-F is the active component of rac-fenoterol. Further evaluation of R-F will determine if it has enhanced selectivity and specificity for beta2-AR/G(s) activation and if it can be used in the treatment of congestive heart failure.    

16920659    Computer-aided molecular design of highly potent HIV-1 RT inhibitors: 3D QSAR and molecular docking studies of efavirenz derivatives.       Ligand- and structure-based design approaches have been applied to an extended series of 74 efavirenz compounds effectively inhibiting wild type (WT) and mutant type (K103N) HIV-1 reverse transcriptase (RT). For ligand-based approach, three dimensional quantitative structure-activity relationship (3D-QSAR) methods, comparative molecular field analysis (CoMFA) and comparative similarity indices analysis (CoMSIA), were performed. The starting geometry of efavirenz was obtained from X-ray crystallographic data. The efavirenz derivatives were constructed and fully optimized by ab-initio molecular orbital method at HF/3-21G level. Reliable QSAR models for high predictive abilities were developed. Regarding WT and K103N inhibitions, CoMFA models with r2/cv = 0.651 and 0.678 and CoMSIA models with r2/cv = 0.662 and 0.743 were derived, respectively. The interpretation obtained from the models highlights different structural requirements for inhibition of WT and K103N HIV-1 RT. To elucidate potential binding modes of efavirenz derivatives in the binding pocket of WT and K103N HIV-1 RT, structure-based approach based on computational docking studies of selected efavirenz compounds were performed by using GOLD and FlexX programs. The results derived from docking analysis give additional information and further probe the inhibitor-enzyme interactions. The correlation of the results obtained from 3D QSAR and docking models validate each other and lead to better understanding of the structural requirements for the activity. Therefore, these integrated results are informative to provide key features and a helpful guideline for novel compound design active against HIV-1 RT.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split text file into multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273069/split-text-file-into-multiple-files)

Comment: In addition to `awk` solution below, try `man csplit` (assuming this is Linux; if not, it may not be available by default).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this should work for your requirement:

```
 awk -v RS="" '{print $0 > $1".txt"}' file
```

the one-liner above will generate 3 files (with your example): `16914261.txt  16917835.txt  16920659.txt` you could adjust the filenames as you want.

Comment: I got an error as awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 {print $0 > >>>  $1".txt" <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1 . Please help me out

Comment: The order of precedence isn't defined with `>` so to be safe you should do `print $0 > ($1".txt")`