# Bash how to split file on empty line with awk

Tags: awk, split, csplit

I have a text file (`A.in`) and I want to split it into multiple files. The split should occur everytime an empty line is found. The filenames should be progressive (`A1.in`, `A2.in`, ..)

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483507/split-paragraphs-of-text-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-empty-line-between-ea) answer that suggests using `awk`, but I can't make it work with my desired naming convention

```
awk -v RS="" '{print $0 > $1".txt"}' file
```

I also found [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016894/how-to-split-a-large-text-file-into-smaller-files-with-equal-number-of-lines) telling me to use the command `csplit -l` but I can't make it match empty lines, I tried matching the pattern `''` but I am not that familiar with regex and I get the following

```
bash-3.2$ csplit A.in ""
csplit: : unrecognised pattern
```

Input file:

***A.in***

```
4 
RURDDD

6
RRULDD
KKKKKK

26
RRRULU
```

Desired output:

***A1.in***

```
4 
RURDDD
```

***A2.in***

```
6
RRULDD
KKKKKK
```

***A3.in***

```
26
RRRULU
```

Comment: I am trying to improve my questions quality to match SOF standards, any feedback on the question would be highly appreciated

Comment: This is a good question and close to SOF standards. The only thing missing is stating what goes wrong with your attempt.

Comment: Right, 2 major things to avoid saying in a question on SO are "it doesn't work" (without an explanation of in what way "it doesn't work") and "I want a one-liner..." (because that implies you favor brevity over all of the things that **really** matter for software like coupling, cohesion, efficiency, portability, clarity, etc. and so would reject a good answer in favor of a brief answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another fix for the awk:

```
$ awk -v RS="" '{
    split(FILENAME,a,".")  # separate name and extension
    f=a[1] NR "." a[2]     # form the filename, use NR as number
    print > f              # output to file
    close(f)               # in case there are MANY to avoid running out f fds
}' A.in
```

Comment: what does NR stand for?

Comment: Record number (well _number of input records awk has processed since the beginning of the program's execution_ based on GNU awk documentation). `RS=""` reparates the records on empty lines and `NR` is awk built-it variable for the count.

Comment: @AlessandroSolbiati note that the solution of James is a bit more robust than mine. This deserves the accepted answer!

Comment: @JamesBrown Consider it an early Christmas gift ;-)

Comment: @kvantour You need to [start voting](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/gonna-find-out), Santa (to get that hat).

Comment: Just be aware the split() approach will fail if/when FILENAME contains more than one `.`. If that's a possibility then `base=sfx=FILENAME; sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"",base); sub(/.*\./,"",sfx); f=base NR "." sfx`.

Answer (score 2):

In any normal case, the following script should work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{ print > ("A" NR ".in") }' file
```

The reason why this might fail is most likely due to some CRLF terminations (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix)).

As mentioned by James, making it a bit more robust as:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{ f = "A" NR ".in"; print > f; close(f) }' file
```

If you want to use `csplit`, the following will do the trick:

```
csplit --suppress-matched  -f "A" -b "%0.2d.in" A.in '/^$/' '{*}'
```

See `man csplit` for understanding the above.

Comment: works as intended. guess I was missing the syntax of BEGIN and c++ for the naming convention. Thank you very much

Comment: @AlessandroSolbiati, most likely you missed the brackets for the redirection. Some versions of awk handle this differently if the brackets are missing.

Comment: @AlessandroSolbiati I have added the `csplit` solution to the problem too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Input file content:

```
$ cat A.in 
4 
RURDDD

6
RRULDD
KKKKKK

26
RRRULU
```

AWK file content:

```
BEGIN{
    n=1
}
{
    if(NF!=0){
        print $0 >> "A"n".in"
    }else{
        n++
    }
}
```

Execution:

```
awk -f ctrl.awk A.in
```

Output:

```
$ cat A1.in 
4 
RURDDD

$ cat A2.in 
6
RRULDD
KKKKKK

$ cat A3.in 
26
RRRULU
```

PS: One-liner execution without AWK file:

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=1}{if(NF!=0){print $0 >> "A"n".in"}else{n++}}' A.in
```

Comment: That will fail with a syntax error in some awks due to unparenthesized right side of redirection and it will fail with a "too many open files" error in most awks due to not closing the output files as you go.

Comment: @EdMorton I've tested the code with awk, gawk, mawk and nawk without errors

Comment: idk which awk you mean when you include just `awk` at the start of that list but there's no way `nawk` at least wouldn't fail when you get past about 20 output file names and here's one example of the syntax error using BSD awk version 20070501 on MacOS: `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 BEGIN{n=1}{if(NF!=0){print $0 >> >>>  "A"n <<< ".in"}else{n++}}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1`