# Report HTTP Response Headers to stderr?

Tags: curl

I have been using `curl -i http://website.com` for a long time. It's great, it reports the response headers and information.

I also use a tool `jq` which parses and pretty prints JSON. I'd like to do the following:

```
curl -i http://website.com | jq -r .
```

The problem with this is that the HTTP headers are forwarded to `jq`.

Is there a way to redirect `-i` to standard error?

Answer (score 27):

Try this command:

`curl -s -D /dev/stderr http://www.website.com/... | jq`

Comment: This does exactly what the OP wants. `-D /dev/stderr` writes the headers to stderr, `-s` removes the progress bars. I often add `-S` so I still get errors if curl fails (which `-s` would otherwise hide).

Comment: `curl -s -D CON http://www.website.com/... | jq .` works on windows. tyvm for the tip in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Since I faced the some problem today, I came up using:

```
curl -i http://some-server/get.json | awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' | awk -v RS= 'NR==1{print > "/dev/stderr";next} 1' > /dev/stdout  | jq .
```

Most likely not the best solution, but it works for me.

Explanation: the first awk program will just convert windows new lines to unix new lines.

In the second program `-v RS=` will instruct awk to use one or more blank lines as record separators<sup>[1]</sup>. `NR==1{print > "/dev/stderr";next}` will print the first record (NR==1) to stderr, the next statement forces awk to immediately stop processing the current record and go on to the next record<sup>[2]</sup>. `1` is just a short hand for `{print $0}`<sup>[3]</sup>.

<sup>[1]</sup> https://stackoverflow.com/a/33297878
<sup>[2]</sup> https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Next-Statement.html
<sup>[3]</sup> https://stackoverflow.com/a/20263611

Comment: hm, I'm getting a redirection (with -L), and the second request headers go to the output sadly :-/