# Get Json body and Response Status from Bash Script POST

Tags: bash, curl

Currently I am using:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROCESS=$(curl --location --request -v -X POST 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"title": "foo","body": "bar","userId": "1"}')

echo "$PROCESS"
```

And getting:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   111  100    67  100    44    208    137 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   344
{
  "title": "foo",
  "body": "bar",
  "userId": "1",
  "id": 101
}
```

But I also want the response status e.g. 201 or like this.

```
HTTP/2 200 
date: Mon, 30 Nov 2020 14:00:56 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
set-cookie: __cfduid=dfda1e85d5738eb18115dc0a07311a4dd1606744856; expires=Wed, 30-Dec-20 14:00:56 GMT; path=/; domain=.typicode.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
x-powered-by: Express
x-ratelimit-limit: 1000
x-ratelimit-remaining: 999
x-ratelimit-reset: 1606702897
vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
access-control-allow-credentials: true
cache-control: max-age=43200
pragma: no-cache
expires: -1
x-content-type-options: nosniff
etag: W/"6b80-Ybsq/K6GwwqrYkAsFxqDXGC7DoM"
via: 1.1 vegur
cf-cache-status: HIT
age: 13185
cf-request-id: 06bb0df15c0000edfbfb9b8000000001
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=ABBCY6aKAHfezboFKgcq%2FlsWKQZDAORup49fKMArhm%2BYl3Kb99pMLrZpLtbXsfz%2BQ6RxnutmzE0mCX5AcIVGRjmq%2FIrIja5MeNFFnmpO7WBT1725PWdN1J0KFhcqNxvNP8He2TBjfd3N"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 5fa518fbcbdfedfb-CDG
```

I want to do the post and the echo out body and response code in a nice way.

Answer (score 0):

Response code is sent in HTTP headers.
You may redirect headers to STDERR e.g. as described here: [Report HTTP Response Headers to stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49057042/report-http-response-headers-to-stderr)

So you may do this:

```
out=$(curl -s -D /dev/stderr http://boardreader.com 2>/tmp/headers)
# parse /tmp/headers
```

If you don't want to mess with temp file, you may try more complex solutions like
[Capture stdout and stderr into different variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027679/capture-stdout-and-stderr-into-different-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You can only issue either a post or header request in one call and so you will need to do this in two separate calls read into the same variable and so:

```
PROCESS=$(curl -I 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' && curl -X POST 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"title": "foo","body": "bar","userId": "1"}')
```

To me it makes sense to check the headers first and if this command is successful, get the json response with both being read into the PROCESS variable. You can of course change the order if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the response, How would I check for the appropriate response code?

Comment: You can try awk '/HTTP\/1.1/ { print $2 }' <<< "$PROCESS"