# Split csv file into multiple files

Tags: bash, unix, split

I have a single huge csv file that contains header line and than hundreds of thousands of records.

I want to split it into multiple files, each containing the same header and than 10.000 records or what's left

If I didn't care about the header, I'd do [`split -l 10000 myfile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273069/split-text-file-into-multiple-files). However, I need each file to contain the header

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the file, exluding the header:

```
tail -n +2 myfile | split -l 10000 - prefix-
```

Get the header line:

```
head -1 myfile > header
```

And then append it to all the generated files:

```
for file in prefix-*; do
   cat header $file > $file.new
   mv $file.new $file
done
```

Comment: thanks! what does the `+2` in the `tail` stand for? I see that it skips the first line, but why does it do it?

Comment: Google "man tail" to get the documentation (MANual) for the *tail* utility. You'll find that `-n +2` tells *tail* to start with the second line, instead of listing the last 10 lines (default)